# Hard Reset ESP32 via NodeJS Application with serialport package

Tags: arduino, serial-port, esp32, node-serialport

Is there a way to hard reset ESP32 from nodeJs application using their serialport package.
While uploading the code to ESP32, there comes a statement at the end. Hard Resetting via RTS pin. Can we do the same from NodeJs app?

Comment: There is a restart() method within ESP class. It is define at [ESP.restart()](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/a38ffe58fe1d73a56295edb0c6051a46932e0175/cores/esp32/Esp.h#L58). It this is not what you are looking for, pls elaborate what is the purpose and user case.

Comment: Sometimes, the ESP stops reading the Serial Input and I need to hard reset physically but want to do it remotely.

Comment: Then you should track down why Serial stop working than trying to hard reset remotely.